# How to create table having one column as sum of other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Create Table Billing3 
(
billingId int primary key,
FoodCharge float DEFAULT 0,
DoctorCharge float DEFAULT 0,
TestCharge float DEFAULT 0,
OperationCharge float DEFAULT 0,
RoomCharge float DEFAULT 0,
Total float DEFAULT (FoodCharge + DoctorCharge + TestCharge + OperationCharge + RoomCharge)
)
```

Comment: Don't store it. Calculate it in your selects.

Comment: I want the table to automatically add up the values

Comment: Yes, I know. Don't do it. :) You need a trigger for that that updates the field all the times something changes. It is way better to just put the logic in the select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can set up a MySQL [insert trigger](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php). But usually, you want to keep calculations in queries as you save on storage and avoid maintenance on a programming object. Plus, if one of the charges updates values, you would then need an update trigger.

```
USE `databasename`;
DELIMITER 
$$
CREATE TRIGGER `TotalCalculation` 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON `Billing3` FOR EACH ROW
-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one
BEGIN
SET NEW.Total = NEW.FoodCharge + NEW.DoctorCharge + NEW.TestCharge +
                NEW.OperationCharge + NEW.RoomCharge;
END
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support calculated columns.  You can use a view for this purpose:

```
create view v_billing3 as
    select b.*,
           (FoodCharge + DoctorCharge + TestCharge + OperationCharge + RoomCharge) as total
    from billing3 b;
```

Also, don't store numbers as floating points.  Instead, use the fixed point type, `decimal`, for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Without trigger you can add by putting as in creation of table itself following below

```sql
CREATE TABLE Billing3 (
billingId INT PRIMARY key,
FoodCharge FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
DoctorCharge FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
TestCharge FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
OperationCharge FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
RoomCharge FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
Total FLOAT DEFAULT AS (FoodCharge + DoctorCharge + TestCharge + OperationCharge + RoomCharge)
)
```